# How to differentiate a programmatic delete from an application delete in crm 2011 plugins

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have an entity with a pre delete plugin. Is it possible to differentiate in the plugin if the delete request has been issued manually in crm or programmatically using the crmservice from the sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know is not possible to differentiate inside a plugin a request made by web interface from another made using the sdk.

Comment: They sadly removed the Origin property which included this information in CRM 4

Comment: Unfortunately not the answer I wanted but will have to deal with it ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could infer it from other information.

If you know a particular user who will always be performing the delete (e.g. a service account), then you could inspect `IPluginExecutionContext.InitiatingUserId`.

Or you could have a 'delete by service' field, don't put that field on the form, then before you issue your delete via the crmservice, update that field to a known value. Then your plugin can just inspect that field.

Not quite as elegant as inspecting an origin field, but you should be able to perform the logic you need.